# Can I "link" two different keys together so that messages with any of those keys end up in the same partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

We know that messages with the same key, `"key1"`, end up in the same partition.

Is it possible to "link" two particular different keys (`"key1"` and `"key2"`) such that messages of any of those keys end up in the same partition?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with the default Partitioner.

In order to do that, you'll need to implement your own [Partitioner](http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html) and configure your Producer to use it using `partitioner.class`.